# Human readable logical permissions in PHP

Tags: php, permissions, logical-operators

So I have a login system, and I store user permissions using an integer column which will be populated with the corresponding permission number. I do it this way to store multiple permissions easily, and to save db queries.

So, these are my permissions:

```
create_user = 1
delete_user = 2
edit_user = 4
```

A user with all those permissions will have a permissions integer value of 7 (1+2+4). However, I need to render the user's permissions in a human readable way.

So **what I need to do is deconstruct the 7 into those three numbers again, preferably in a comma separated string (`1,2,4`)** but I can't come up with a function to do that.

UPDATE: I want to do this because then I will take those integers and translate them according to their value, so the end user can see clearly what the permissions are. So, `1,2,4` will become `Create User,Delete User, Edit User`.

Any wisdom from you guys?

Comment: define readable constants

Comment: Yes, I understand that. However, what if I grow to have like 30 different permissions? I can't have a constant to translate each possible combination.

Comment: PERMITION_CREATE+PERMITION_DELETE - for example. And `if($right & PERMITION_CREATE) {...}`

Comment: What does your tables schema look like? Is the permissions column simply an `int` column in your users table where users have an integer value of 7 if you want them to have all 3 of the permissions in the above example?

Comment: It's just an integer 7. What I really need to know is how can I deconstruct that 7 into a `1,2,4` string. Or even know if that is possible.

Comment: Such a setup will get messy VERY fast, if you end up with 30 different permissions - which ALL will need to have a distinct value COMBINED with other values to ALL end up with different end results. Which will take A LOT of math to manage. Why not just have a proper user-level setting, or just boolean values on/off based per user-login?

Comment: if you want to use this way then why not use a column called permission and put a string inside c then can create user d then can delete user e then can edit user then use php to check if there is a c d or e in the string before allow the action?

Comment: I understand. However, this is a common practice to manage user permissions. So it must be a way to create a function that will translate the integer (no matter how big it is) easily.

Comment: Good idea, @Gert. But not very conventional.

Comment: @MatíasNavarroCarter not so common way to do user management special not counting the numbers

Comment: UNIX manages user permissions like that (777).

Comment: *what I need to do is deconstruct the 7 into those three numbers again*  -  for what purpose? what is result of such function?

Comment: I was going to say, you can look into how UNIX does it. There are easier ways though as mentioned such as boolean values for each permission (either in the users table or in a FK linked permissions table). Or a full-blown RBAC system, where you can assign permissions to groups and then assign groups to users.

Comment: the right way is to create a table with privileges for users , then include everything the user can do in that table, then when do the function check if the allowance is in the array if yes execute if not tell them  they don't have permission

Comment: Thnaks for all your useful sugestions. I was google'ing how UNIX does it, but I couldn't find any info about it.

I was thinking to change the whole user permission system to booleans as @Optimae suggested. I'll do that if I can't manage to do this. But a RBAC and other approaches are discarded, since they use the database. Memory and DB usage is a huge concern for my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use binary comparison with a single ampersand, like @splash58 suggested.

```
$permission = 7;

if ($permission & 1 == 1) {
    // user has "create_user" permissions
}

if ($permission & 2 == 2) {
    // user has "delete_user" permissions
}

if ($permission & 4 == 4) {
    // user has "edit_user" permissions
}
```

Most systems that use this kind of technique for permission management, try to at least define human-readable constants, just in case you ever need to change the integers:

```
define('CREATE_USER', 1);
define('DELETE_USER', 2);
define('EDIT_USER', 4);

$permission = 7;

if ($permission & CREATE_USER == CREATE_USER) {
    // user has "create_user" permissions
}
```

I've used similar types of authorization systems in the past, and I'd always create a function I could call to check whether a user has a specific permission wherever I needed to place some restricted link or check if they were allowed to view a particular page:

```
/**
 * Checks whether a user's rights contains a particular permission
 *
 * @var int $rights     sum of a user's rights
 * @var int $permission permission to check for
 * @return bool
 */
function has_permission($rights, $permission) {
    return ($rights & $permission == $permission);
}
```

By using constants, you can then call it in quite a readable fashion:

```
$permission = 7;

if (has_permission($permission, CREATE_USER)) {
    // show the button to create a new user
}
```

If you really need to fully deconstruct the user's permissions (say, you need to get an array of all permissions a user has), I'd dump all available permissions in an array and create a function that loops through them:

```
/**
 * Returns an array of all permissions a user has
 *
 * @var int   $rights      sum of a user's rights
 * @var int[] $permissions list of all known permissions
 * @return int[]
 */
function get_permissions($rights, $permissions) {
    $user_permissions = array();

    foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
        if ($rights & $permission == $permission) {
            $user_permissions[] = $permission;
        }
    }

    return $user_permissions;
}

$permissions = array(
    CREATE_USER,
    DELETE_USER,
    EDIT_USER,
    ...
);

$rights = DELETE_USER + EDIT_USER; // 6
$user_permissions = get_permissions($rights, $permissions);
// [2, 4]
```

This single ampersand binary comparison thing works like this:

```
1 in binary: 001
2 in binary: 010
4 in binary: 100
7 in binary: 111

7 & 1:
    111
    001
    ^   both are not 1, so 0
     ^  both are not 1, so 0
      ^ both ARE 1, so 1
    ---
    001 -> is equal to 1, so 7 & 1 == 1 and user has "create_user" permissions
```

That's why you can check if `7 & 1 == 1`, because if `$permission` were 6 (only "delete_user" and "edit_user" permissions), you would get this result:

```
6 in binary: 110

6 & 1:
    110
    001
    ^   both are not 1, so 0
     ^  both are not 1, so 0
      ^ both are not 1, so 0
    ---
    000 -> is NOT equal to 1, so no "create_user" permissions
```

Comment: Great! This will suit my needs, since I have my permissions in a constant array. So will be easy to loop through them every time I want to.

PS: I really need to learn more binary!

Comment: Thanks a lot, by the way! @rickdenhaan